# Can one find Dirac matrices for any spacetime metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, topology, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

For any metric $$g_{μν}$$ is there always a linearly independant spacetime algebra satisfying $$\{\bar{γ}_μ,\bar{γ}_ν\} = 2 g_{μν} I?$$

For a diagonal metric I was able to work out that $$\bar{γ}_μ=\sqrt{n_{μμ}*g_{μμ}}γ_μ$$ satisfied these conditions (the minkowski simply adds negatives to cancel the spacelike gammas). However for metrics which are not diagonalizable at every point in spacetime I've been having trouble.

$$+---$$ is being used here.

Playing around with Tetrads seems like the way to go but I havent had as much luck this far. Thanks in advance to any help!

Comment: The spacetime manifold should be a [spin manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure).

Comment: @Qmechanic Are you sure about that? Where there exist obstructions to the construction of a spin structure, the construction of the Clifford algebra bundle is functorial, so that all pseudo-Riemannian manifolds have a Clifford bundle. In any case, I think the OP is thinking of Minkowski space but representations by possibly non-orthonormal matrices $\gamma_\mu$.

Comment: @doetoe I'm thinking more spacetimes like the Kerr metric. Metrics for which there is no coordinate system which can diagonalize the metric everywhere.

Comment: @Craig OK. Could we read your question as "Let a manifold be given with a pseudo-Riemannian metric $g_{\mu\nu}$. Is it possible to find a smoothly varying set of linearly independent matrices $\gamma_\mu$ for which $$\{\gamma_\mu,\gamma_\nu\} = 2 g_{\mu\nu} I$$ holds at every point?"

Comment: @doetoe yes this is precisely what I meant :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, tetrads are the way to go. Suppose we have Dirac matrices for Minkowski space,
$$
  \{ \gamma^a, \gamma^b \} = 2 \eta^{ab} I,
$$
and we also have a tetrad/vierbein, $e_a^\mu$, [1]
$$
  g_{\mu\nu}\ e_a^\mu\ e_b^\nu = \eta_{ab},
  \qquad
  \eta^{ab}\ e_a^\mu\ e_b^\nu = g^{\mu\nu}.
$$
Then we can define $\bar{\gamma}^\mu$:
$$
  \bar{\gamma}^\mu = e_a^\mu\ \gamma^a,
  \qquad
  \{ \bar{\gamma}^\mu, \bar{\gamma}^\nu \}
    = e_a^\mu\ e_b^\nu\ \{ \gamma^a, \gamma^b \}
    = e_a^\mu\ e_b^\nu\  2 \eta^{ab} I
    = 2 g^{\mu\nu} I.
$$
When dealing with spinors in curved space, people usually stick to the tetrad formalism.

References:
Carroll, Spacetime and geometry (the last appendix).
Weinberg, The Quantum Theory of Fields: Volume 3 (Section 31.1)

[1] As alluded to by *Qmechanic* and *doetoe* in the comments above, there can be topological problems with finding a tetrad or defining spinors. I'd ask them for references if you want to know more about this.

Comment: Wow thank you for answering this months after it was posted! I really do appreciate it! :)